# For a period of time cumulative sum in R

Tags: r

```
  id   date     goal      date_followup_3month  cumulative_sum
  1 2004-12-31    1           2005-03-31              3
  1 2005-01-21    2           2005-04-21              6
  1 2005-04-04    3           2005-07-03              4
  1 2005-04-04    1           2005-07-03              1
  2 2001-01-05    4           2001-04-05              4
  2 2002-02-05    3           2002-05-06              5
```

`cumulative_sum` column is the cumulative value of the goal from date to three months for each ID.

The code I thought was as below and the result is not coming out.

> error code :  argument "yes" is missing, with no default

```
for(i in 1:length(id)){

    cumulative_sum[i] <-  for(j in 1:length(id))
    {max(cumsum(ifelse(id[i] == id[j]
                       & date[j] >= date[i]
                       & date[j] <= date_followup_3month[i])
                ,goal[j],0))}

}
```

I want to know if there is any other good code. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please show the expected output and what you want to achieve.

Comment: the ouput I want is cumulative_sum column and The value of the final line of the column must be 3. I would like to obtain accumulated values of the corresponding goal for a period of three months from the date of the row.

Comment: How do you want to treat the duplicated `id = 1, date = 2005-04-04`? Why is `2005-04-04 + 3M`equal to `2005-07-03` and not `2005-07-04`?

Comment: First, your closing bracket in your ifelse statement is not correct. That is the reason for the error. You close the ifelse after your condition. It should be moved after the 0. Also make a better expected output and put that in your question.

Answer (score 4):

Here are several possibilities.  The SQL based solution (1) seems highly readable and is potentially space efficient since SQL may optimize the join.  The data.table solution (2) creates a large intermediate result but see the comment by @Frank to avoid that.  Even larger intermediate results are created in (3) and (4) which may not be feasible if the data is sufficiently large.  The loop based solution (5) is space efficient but uses a style not normally used in R.  (5) can be translated to C++ (using Rcpp) in a straight forard way which we show in (6).

**1) sqldf** This can be expressed in SQL using a self join on a complex logical condition:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select a.*, sum(b.goal) cumulative_sum
  from DF a
  join DF b on a.id = b.id and b.rowid >= a.rowid and b.date <= a.date_followup_3month
  group by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
  id       date goal date_followup_3month cumulative_sum
1  1 2004-12-31    1           2005-03-31              3
2  1 2005-01-21    2           2005-04-21              6
3  1 2005-04-04    3           2005-07-03              4
4  1 2005-04-04    1           2005-07-03              1
5  2 2001-01-05    4           2001-04-05              4
6  2 2002-02-05    3           2002-05-06              3
```

**2) data.table**   This can be done in data.table as well although note that this involves creating an intermediate object with a large number of rows whereas sql may optimize that away.

```
library(data.table)

DT <- as.data.table(DF)
DT[, seq:=.I][
  DT, on = .(id == id, seq <= seq, date_followup_3month >= date)][
  , list(id = id[1], 
         date = date[1], 
         date_followup_3month = date_followup_3month[1],
         cumulative_sum = sum(i.goal)), by = seq]
```

**3) Base R** Here is a base solution which performs a self join explicitly over id only and then subsets the rows down for the other terms in the condition.  Finally it uses `tapply` to perform the summation.  It involves explicitly generating `s` which is an even larger intermediate result.

```
DF0 <- cbind(seq = 1:nrow(DF), DF)
s <- subset(merge(DF0, DF0, by = "id"), 
       seq.x <= seq.y & date_followup_3month.x >= date.y)
transform(DF, cumulative_sum = tapply(s$goal.y, s$seq.x, sum))
```

**4) dplyr**  This uses dplyr and like (3) involves a potentially very large intermediate result since it performs a self join with respect only to id.

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
  mutate(seq = 1:n()) %>% 
  inner_join(., ., by = "id", suffix = c("", ".x")) %>%
  filter(seq.x >= seq & date.x <= date_followup_3month) %>%
  group_by(seq, date, goal, date_followup_3month) %>%
  summarize(cumulative_sum = sum(goal.x)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-seq)
```

**5) Loop - Base R** Explicit looping is discouraged in R and can be slow but on the other hand it is relatively straight forward and space efficient.  This could be used as a model to translate the code to C++ which we do in the solution following this one.  Note that we included several optimizations.  Because the input is sorted the j loop can start from i, rather than from 1, and as soon as the condition in the j loop fails we can immediately exit the j loop as the satisfying rows necessarily all occur together.

```
n <- nrow(DF)
Sum <- numeric(n)
for(i in 1:n) {
  for(j in i:n) {
    if (with(DF, id[i] == id[j] && date[j] <= date_followup_3month[i])) {
      Sum[i] <- Sum[i] + DF$goal[j]
    } else break
  }
}
transform(DF, cumulative_sum = Sum)
```

**6) Rcpp** We can translate (5) to C++.  Assume we have a file called cum_sum.cpp containing this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector cum_sum(NumericVector id, IntegerVector date, 
  IntegerVector date_followup_3month, NumericVector goal) {
  auto n = id.size();
  NumericVector Sum(n);
  for(auto i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    Sum[i] = 0.0;
    for(auto j = i; j < n; j++) {
      if (id[i] == id[j] && date[j] <= date_followup_3month[i]) {
        Sum[i] = Sum[i] + goal[j];
      } else break;
    }
  }
  return Sum;
}
```

Then run:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("cum_sum.cpp")
transform(DF, cumulative_sum = 
                cum_sum(id, date, date_followup_3month, as.numeric(goal)))
```

### Note

The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "id   date     goal      date_followup_3month
  1 2004-12-31    1           2005-03-31
  1 2005-01-21    2           2005-04-21
  1 2005-04-04    3           2005-07-03
  1 2005-04-04    1           2005-07-03
  2 2001-01-05    4           2001-04-05
  2 2002-02-05    3           2002-05-06"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
DF$date <- as.Date(DF$date)
DF$date_followup_3month <- as.Date(DF$date_followup_3month)
```

Comment: The large intermediate object with data.table can be avoided using `DT[DT, j, by=.EACHI]` instead of `DT[DT][, j, by=seq]`, eg like `DT[, seq := .I][, v := DT[.(id = id, seq = seq, d_dn = date, d_up = date_followup_3month), on=.(id, seq >= seq, date >= d_dn, date <= d_up), sum(x.goal), by=.EACHI]$V1][]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use just sum for the lines which satisfy condition on dates and id instead of max(cumsum). Also to avoid nested loops, function could be use. Example with some simplification is below:

```
      goalsum <- function(date, i){
      start <- date$date[i]
      end <- date$date_followup_3month[i]
      ind <- date$id[i]
      tot_goal <- date%>%
        filter(date>=start & date<=end & id==ind)%>%
        summarise(sum(goal))
      return(tot_goal[1,1])
    }

    for(i in 1:length(date)){date$res[i] <-goalsum(date, i)}
```